# [SOLVED] fedora: rqt_plot runtime error

Tags: ros-kinetic, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ROS Kinetic on Fedora 29.
After running successfully these commands:

```
rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key
rqt_graph
```

I try to run `rqt_plot /turtle1/pose/x /turtle1/pose/y` or equivalently `rqt_plot /turtle1/pose/x:y` and it gives the following error:

```
Warning: QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:
   QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to enable platform plugin controlled per-screen factors.
   QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS to set per-screen factors.
   QT_SCALE_FACTOR to set the application global scale factor.
PluginManager._load_plugin() could not load plugin "rqt_plot/Plot":
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Giuseppe/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler.py", line 99, in load
    self._load()
  File "/home/Giuseppe/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler_direct.py", line 54, in _load
    self._plugin = self._plugin_provider.load(self._instance_id.plugin_id, self._context)
  File "/home/Giuseppe/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 71, in load
    instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/home/Giuseppe/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 71, in load
    instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/home/Giuseppe/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rqt_gui_py/ros_py_plugin_provider.py", line 60, in load
    return super(RosPyPluginProvider, self).load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/home/Giuseppe/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 71, in load
    instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/home/Giuseppe/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rqt_gui/ros_plugin_provider.py", line 101, in load
    return class_ref(plugin_context)
  File "/home/Giuseppe/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rqt_plot/plot.py", line 55, in __init__
    self._data_plot = DataPlot(self._widget)
  File "/home/Giuseppe/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rqt_plot/data_plot/__init__.py", line 149, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError('No usable plot type found. Install at least one of: PyQtGraph, MatPlotLib (at least %s) or Python-Qwt5.' % version_info)
RuntimeError: No usable plot type found. Install at least one of: PyQtGraph, MatPlotLib (at least 1.4.0) or Python-Qwt5.
```

So I've checked these three libraries and it seems they're all installed:
-for PyQtGraph I have `python3-pyqtgraph`
-for MatPlotLib I have `python2-matplotlib`
-for Python-Qwt5 I have  `PyQwt-5.2.0-40.fc29.src.rpm`
So I don't get why this is not working properly since I have all of them.
Anyway, I think that instead of `python3-pyqtgraph` I should install `python2-pyqtgraph` but `dnf` doesn't find it because it's an old version I think (or maybe it is deprecated).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319745/%5Bsolved%5D-fedora:-rqt_plot-runtime-error/) by [0novanta](https://answers.ros.org/users/40578/0novanta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved by running `sudo pip install PyQtGraph`

---

Originally posted by [0novanta](https://answers.ros.org/users/40578/0novanta/) with karma: 18 on 2019-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cottsay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3167/cottsay/) on 2019-09-17**:
This is the right way to work around this. For context, `python2-pyqtgraph` was dropped prior to the Fedora 30 release: https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/python-pyqtgraph/c/99946ff0e44ba9241e6c2a3ffc56bf1f77b0554e?branch=master